# Use jQuery to copy text from one location, to replace text elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace, copy

I've been struggling with this for hours so hope someone can please help.

I have a dropdown menu (.category-navbar) which filters images shown below it. Whichever item is selected in the list is given the class '.select' - what I want is to have a label above that which displays the text of the selected list item.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-portfolio">
  <label>All</label> // This is the text I want to update
  <ul class="category-navbar">
    <li class="select">
      <a>All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The label will initially show the text 'All' (as that is the default list item), but I want that to change when one of the other menu items are selected ie. 'Item2', 'Item3' etc.

Below is the code showing what I think I need, I've tried variations of this but nothing has worked - I've put 'copy' and 'replace' to show want I want to happen.

```
$(".category-navbar li a").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .copy(".select a").text()
    .replace(".dropdown-menu-portfolio label").text();
});
```

Whilst trying to get anything to work, I found the code below does work, but obviously isn't right as it adds the newly selected item after the label, also it adds the text as a link, whereas I only want plain text.

```
$(".category-navbar li a").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .clone(".select a")
    .appendTo(".dropdown-menu-portfolio label");
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
$(".category-navbar li a").click(function() {
    // Modifying the label
    $('div.dropdown-menu-portfolio label').text($(this).text());

    // Removing the class 'select' to the item previously selected
    $('li.select').removeClass('select');

    // Giving the class 'select' to the item currently selected
    $(this).parent().addClass('select');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly (I only needed the label modifying) - wish I had posted this 3 hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this.  Just try

```
$(".dropdown-menu-portfolio label").text($(this).text());
```

Your syntax was wrong aside from this better solution.

Comment: @user3326054 Your welcome, even though I don't get how it would not work.